# Get the page which a record is in

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am using this code snippet to do paging

```
public IQueryable<RecordModel> GetSource()
{
    return entities.RecordModel.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
}

public List<RecordModel> Paging(IQueryable<T> source)
{
   return source.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList();
}
```

After a user has added a new record, I wish to show the new record in a list. If the list is paged, I would like to show the user the page that the new record is in. I'm using EF4 to add in the new record, something like:

```
public void AddRecord(RecordModel record)
{
  entities.AddObject(record); 
  entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

How do I find out which page a record is in?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an alternative solution.

If you have a field like `CreationDate` then show the first page sorted by `CreationDate` descending order.